# How to add localization for cal extension in TYPO3

Tags: typo3, typo3-7.6.x

I'm using the TYPO3 7.6 version and "Cal" extension 1.11.1.
I want to localize the Days text on the header of calendar but this didn't work, I have added all settings for the foreign language and this is working for news extension text "Read more", but this didn't run for the cal extension. How can I fix this?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure wether ext:cal is using it, but getting day- and month-names often is done by php accessing the system information. Therefore you need to have a proper `locale` definition matching the available locales on your system.

Get a list of available locals:

```
locale -a
```

Configuration example in typoscript setup:

```
config.language = de
// here an exact entry of command output above is needed:
config.locale_all = de_DE.utf8
config.htmlTag_langKey = de
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply, i have added the typoscript config as you mentioned but i still get no locales when adding this to link: typo3conf/ext/cal/misc/locales.php

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem recently. I've set the locale as Bernd wrote in his answer and this worked fine for EXT:news but not EXT:cal.

Here is my workaround:

**Fluid Template:**

```
<f:cObject typoscriptObjectPath="lib.formatDate" data="{f:format.date(format:'U', date:'@{event.start.time}')}" />
```

**TypoScript:**

```
lib.formatDate = TEXT
lib.formatDate {
  current = 1
  strftime = %B
}
```

Not very beautiful, but it works ;)